# How to typecast single element of List<double> as type 'double' in calculation in C#

Tags: c#

Suppose I have an initialized list: `List<double> o`

I'd like to perform the following:

```
 int offset = 10;

 for (int i = 0; i < o.Count; ++i){
     o[i] = ApplyRamp(o[i]-offset)
 }
```

where ApplyRamp is defined as:

```
 public static void ApplyRamp(ref double x)
 {
     if (x < 0) x = 0;
 }
```

But the code won't compile. Why isn't the single element of a `List<double>`, i.e. `o[i]`, not treated as type `double`?

Comment: What is the _complete_ compiler error message exactly?

Comment: `ApplyRamp` is returning void and your `o[i]` is type of double

Comment: You assign return of ApplyRamp to a variable, but ApplyRamp is void!

Comment: the error is :T he best overloaded method match for 'MathEq.Functions.ApplyRamp(ref double)' has some invalid arguments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are four problems here:

- You have to use `ref` on the *argument* as well as the parameter
- The expression `o[i] - offset` is classified as a *value* rather than a *variable*, so you can't pass it by reference
- Even the expression `o[i]` would be classified as a value, as it's the result of calling an indexer. If `o` were a `double[]` (i.e. an array instead of a list) then `o[i]` would be classified as a variable.
- You're trying to use the result of a `void` method as the right-hand side of an assignment operator. A `void` method doesn't *have* a result.

You could use:

```
double temp = o[i] - offset;
ApplyRamp(ref temp);
// Do something with temp?
```

But it's not clear what you'd do with `temp` afterwards anyway. Are you trying to modify `o`? If so, where does `offset` come in? And why would you be assigning to `o[i]` as well in that case?

Finally, I'd strongly urge you to consider making your `ApplyRamp` just use a regular by-value parameter and *return* the result instead. That will make it easier to use in most cases. I rarely see a good use of `ref` parameters in `void` methods.

So something like:

```
public static double ApplyRamp(double x)
{
    return x < 0 ? 0 : x;
}
```

Or just use `Math.Max`:

```
public static double ApplyRamp(double x)
{
    return Math.Max(x, 0);
}
```

Comment: The reason I chose `ref` instead of returning an actual value is because the code has to calculate hundreds of them, so I figured using `ref` would save memory. So is `o[i]` treated as type `double`?

Comment: @5422time: Yes, `o[i]` is a `double`. Firstly, you should concentrate on correctness before performance. Secondly, you should only optimize based on measurement rather than guesswork. I suspect you're a bit confused about what `ref` actually does - see http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html

Answer (score 2):

You can't assign `void` to any variable, I think you should change signature of your method:

```
 public static double ApplyRamp(double x)
 {
     if (x < 0) return 0;
     return x;
 }
```

Now your method will return double and will assign this value to `o[i]` element.

[void type description](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yah0tteb.aspx)

> When used as the return type for a method, void specifies that the method doesn't return a value.

And obviously you want to return a value here. Because (as I suppose), you want to adjust `x` to be non-negative. So I think changing your code to return double is best way.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to get a list with the same values, but decreased by `offset` or equal to 0 for values which are less than `offset`, you can use LINQ `Select`.
It will create a new `List<double>` by applying a calculating function to the every item in your `o` array, and then will assign this `List` back to `o`:

```
o = o.Select(x => x - offset < 0 ? 0 : x - offset).ToList();
```

or

```
o = o.Select(x => Math.Max(x - offset, 0)).ToList();
```

Comment: That doesn't modify the existing list, which appears to be what the OP is trying to do.

Comment: @JonSkeet Honestly said, I do not understand what you mean :) It creates a new list by applying these calculations to the every item and assigns it back to `o`, but the result is the same.

Comment: No, creating a new list is not the same as modifying as existing list. In some cases it can be a viable alternative, but not always.

Comment: @JonSkeet Oh, I see. I have updated my answer in order to not confuse the OP. Thank you!

Comment: That still doesn't do the same thing. Yes, it modifies `o` to refer to the new list, but what if another variable also had a reference to the same list?